# Internal Server Error due to htaccess rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have this .htaccess rule and i dont really know what it means, i grabbed it from internet  and changed it according to my needs but it is not working and causing the internal server error. When i remove this rule from .htaccess file then there is no internal server error.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^outsourcelocally.com/about-us-2$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.outsourcelocally.com/about-us-2$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.olocally.com/about$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP_HOST does not contain the request url.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?outsourcelocally\.com$
  RewriteRule ^about-us-2$ http://www.olocally.com/about [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: i want to redirect `outsourcelocally.com/about-us-2` to `www.olocally.com/about` what would be the correct syntax for that?

Comment: Just remove the `$0` from my previous code. I have updated my reply accordingly.